# How to structure and retrieve all nested data from groups which a user is a member of in Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to find a way in Firestore in which i can retrieve nested data from the groups a user is a member of.

A user can for example join several groups and retrieve all groups. I achieve this with this code.

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("Maingroups").whereField("groupmember", arrayContains: userProfile.uid)
            .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
```

but how can a user retrieve all chatrooms from the groups in which he is a member of.

1. This would require me to first filter through all groups and retrieve the ones he is a member of.
2. Retrieve all chatrooms from the groups he is a member of.

As a temporary workaround I've thought about moving this logic to a cloud function. Here's a shorthand of how i imagine it works.

```
for (let group of firestore().collection("Maingroups")) { let user = firestore.doc(groups/${group.id}/users/${uid}); if (user.exists) { // Send this group id to the client
```

After locking the certain groups i hope to be able to retrieve the desired information.

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("Maingroups/documentId/Chatrooms")
```

I have switched to Firestore from Realtime Database in an attempt to solve this problem. So any help on database structure or relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I'm attempting to do make read locked down to the groups that they have been added to. Here's how this would look with a hypothetical subcollection-contains-id operator.
firestore()
.collection("groups")
.where("users", "subcollection-contains-id", user.uid);
As a temporary workaround I've thought about moving this logic to a cloud function. Here's a shorthand of how it works.
for (let group of firestore().collection("groups")) {
let user = firestore.doc(`groups/${group.id}/users/${uid}`);
if (user.exists) {
// Send this group id to the client